# Linear Search using functions and dynamic memory allocation in C

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, linear-search

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define LIMIT 30000

void CreateArray(int *p, int N) {
    int i;
    p = (int *)malloc(N * sizeof(int));
    srand((long)210);
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
        *(p + i) = rand() % LIMIT;

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
        printf("%d ", p[i]);
}

void Search(int *p, int N, int key) {
    int comparisons = 0, success_search = 0;
    int i;

    clock_t start, end;
    double elapsed;
    start = clock();

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        if (key == p[i]) {
            comparisons++;
            success_search++;
            printf("\nFound!");
            break;
        } else {
            comparisons++;
            printf("\nNot found!");
        }
    }

    end = clock();
    elapsed = ((double)(end - start)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    printf("\nTotal comparisons: %d \n", comparisons);
    printf("Time elapsed: %f \n", elapsed);
    printf("Successful comparisons: %d \n\n", success_search);
}

int main() {
    int N, i, p, key;

    key = 1;
    CreateArray(&p, N = 7);
    Search(&p, N, key);
}
```

I'm trying to create a pseudo-random array and then try to search for a specific number in it and keep track of the total comparisons made and the total time needed to complete the search. I have manually inserted a number that is not in the array and it keeps saying that the number was found after 3 comparisons. Also the time elapsed always appears to be zero. I can't figure out what's wrong.

Comment: `int *p;` => `CreateArray(&p, N = 7);` => `void CreateArray (int **p, int N)` => `*p = (int*) malloc (N*sizeof(int));`

Comment: "the time elapsed always appears to be zero" perhaps because of the granularity of the timer. For example Windows MSVC has `#define CLOCKS_PER_SEC  ((clock_t)1000)`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY If i do the changes you recommend, the program won't even start. I get program stopped working error.

Comment: [DEMO](http://ideone.com/mAQrQm)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY is right, but the argument to CreateArray() must be a pointer to a pointer, not a pointer to a stack variable.

Comment: You should improve the debug printing and get the operation of the code correct before you bother worrying about the time.  A linear search of an array of 7 elements is barely going to take microseconds on a modern computer, but the resolution of `clock` is typically in the range 1-20 milliseconds.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY You're right, it's working. Hmm, what if i want to do the search e.g 1000 times with a different number to find each time, how can i get the total number of comparisons, total time for searching and total number of successful searches? I have to return the 3 variables from the Search function to main? How can i return 3 variables with 1 function?

Comment: @user3120283 1) return struct. 2) pointer argument.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I don't want struct, so i tried it the other way but something is wrong with my counters and i can't figure out what i did wrong. Here's a [demo](http://ideone.com/c1mrUk) where i try to run the search 100 times, each time with a different key. I want to get the total number of comparisons made, the successful searches and the total search time in these 100 times. I appreciate all your help

Comment: @user3120283 `(*comparisons++)` --> `(*comparisons)++` or `++*comparisons`, and Need initialize e.g. `comparisons=0, total_comparisons=0` and `comparisons` and `success_search` reset to `0` before call (or at first of inside of function).

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I managed to fix the comparisons and success_search counters. But time elapsed is still not working. Even with e.g N = 5000 i get time elapsed = 0 (i'm using codeblocks). [here](http://ideone.com/c1mrUk)

Comment: try Use `%g` instead of `%f`. Since the value is very small. Also `total_elapsed` isn't initialized.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY So eventually i'm trying to do [this](http://ideone.com/c1mrUk). It seems that when N is low like e.g 5000 i get almost every time 0 successful searches and when N is high (like over 60000) i always get 100% success. The results seem weird to me. Are they normal?

Comment: try `srand(time(NULL));` befor for-loop at **main**. (Delete `srand` in `CreateArray`)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Thank you so much for this!! It finally works as it should. You sir, deserve a cookie! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Make the following changes.

1) You need to allocate array and pass it to different functions. So "n" should be a pointer.

```
int *n = NULL;
```

2) You want CreateArray() to allocate memory and pass the pointer.

```
void CreateArray (int **p, int N)
```

3) You have to pass pointer to Search(). So call from main() becomes

```
Search(p, N, key);
```

I think it should work fine as expected now.

For time elapsed, you refer to Weather Vane's comment in your question.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- `CreateArray` should **return** the pointer to the allocated space. Passing it a pointer to a local `int` in `main()` makes no sense.
- you should test for `malloc` potential failure.
- `Search` should get the pointer to the allocated array, not the address of a local `int`.
- `Search` should print the `Not found` message just once at the end of the scan phase.
- If you want to count the number of *successful comparisons*, you should not break from the loop when you find the first one, but then the total number of comparisons is `N`.
- for better timing accuracy, you should avoid using `printf` inside the timed fragment.
- you should `free` the memory before exiting the program.

Here is a corrected version:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define LIMIT 30000

void CreateArray(int N) {
    int i;
    int *p = (int *)malloc(N * sizeof(int));
    if (p != NULL) {
        srand((long)210);
        for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
            *(p + i) = rand() % LIMIT;

        for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
            printf("%d ", p[i]);
    }
    return p;
}

void Search(int *p, int N, int key) {
    int comparisons = 0, success_search = 0;
    int i;

    clock_t start, end;
    double elapsed;
    start = clock();

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        comparisons++;
        if (key == p[i])
            success_search++;
    }
    end = clock();
    elapsed = ((double)(end - start)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    if (success_search)
        printf("Found!\n");
    else
        printf("Not found!\n");

    printf("Total comparisons: %d\n", comparisons);
    printf("Successful comparisons: %d\n\n", success_search);
    printf("Time elapsed: %f\n", elapsed);
}

int main() {
    int N, i, key;
    int *p;

    key = 1;
    N = 7;
    p = CreateArray(N);
    if (p == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot allocate memory for %d elements\n", N);
        return 1;
    }
    Search(p, N, key);
    free(p);
    return 0;
}
```